# The name of ethernet interface for my network

Tags: ip, ethernet

Why no enp1s0 ethernet interface in my os?

```
ip -brief link |cut -d" "  -f1
lo
enp6s0
```

Why can't get the result ?

```
ip -brief link |cut -d" "  -f1
lo
enp1s0
```

Comment: What is exactly your question? Why your interface is named `enp6s0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ethernet interface name `enp6s0` means the PCI bus location (as indicated by e.g. the `lspci` command) of that NIC is `06:00.0`.

If you don't have a network card at PCI bus location `01:00.0`, you won't get interface name `enp1s0`. On many desktop motherboards, the PCI bus location `01:00.0` refers to the first long (16x) PCIe slot, which is the recommended installation location of the first add-on GPU card.

Of course, if you set custom names for your network interfaces, you can name them anything you like, but if you deliberately break the relationship between the `enp*` names and the corresponding PCI bus locations without a very good reason, you would just cause confusion for yourself (and potentially other administrators of the system) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention for ethernet interfaces has been changed in some recent distributions of Linux. The interface names are now decided dynamically based on it's drivers.

For an in-depth explanation, [see this article.](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)